# Python psql split into respective column

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

I am having a bit of trouble in determining which days have more than 1% of status errors here is the table:

```
 path   | text                     |
 ip     | inet                     |
 method | text                     |
 status | text                     |
 time   | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 id     | integer                  | not null default nextval('log_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "log_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

the important parts are status which is either 200 OK or an error and time which is the date, the rest is kinda useless for this particular problem i believe

and this is the code i have so far:

```
def heavy_error_days():
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=news")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("select date(log.time), errors\
     from log, (select count(status)::numeric/(select count(status)\
     from log)from log where status <> '200 OK'\
     and date(log.time) = date(log.time)) as errors\
     group by date, errors")
    print c.fetchone()
```

i believe what i need to do is to multiply the errors by 100 and split them into their respective date, but i dont know how to write it.

if anyone can help me with this i would be very grateful.

**Error**

```
  File "news.py", line 33
    c.execute("with a as (select distinct (sum(case when status <> '200 OK' then 1 else 0 end) over w * 100) / count(1) over w perc, "time"::date d from log window w as (partition by "time"::date))select * from a where perc > 1")
                                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i noticed that the time was in double quotes and that might be the problem so i changed it to single quotes and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "news.py", line 41, in <module>
    heavy_error_days()
  File "news.py", line 33, in heavy_error_days
    c.execute("with a as (select distinct (sum(case when status <> '200 OK' then 1 else 0 end) over w * 100) / count(1) over w perc, 'time'::date d from log window w as (partition by 'time'::date))select * from a where perc > 1")
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type date: "time"
LINE 1: ...else 0 end) over w * 100) / count(1) over w perc, 'time'::da...
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query should do the trick:

```
with a as (
  select distinct (sum(case when status <> '200 OK' then 1 else 0 end) over w * 100) / count(1) over w perc, "time"::date d
  from log
  window w as (partition by "time"::date)
)
select *
from a
where perc > 1
```

based on example:

build:

```
t=# create table log("time" timestamptz, status text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into log values (now(),'200 OK'),(now(),'200 OK'),(now(),'ERR'),(now()-'2 days'::interval,'200 OK');
INSERT 0 4
```

query:

```
t=# with a as (
  select distinct (sum(case when status <> '200 OK' then 1 else 0 end) over w * 100) / count(1) over w perc, "time"::date d
  from log
  window w as (partition by "time"::date)
)
select *
from a
where perc >= 0
;
 perc |     d
------+------------
    0 | 2017-05-17
   33 | 2017-05-19
(2 rows)
```

Comment: when i try to execute this query it tells me there is a syntax error in the last where

Comment: im running it on python using psycopg im going to update my post with the error so that it is better formatted

Comment: @DanielCampos I checked the error - you have to escape double quotes for `"time"` to be `\"time\"` - just changing double quotes to single quotes changes the whole query. the 'time' is literal and the "time" is identifier - it's not just any of quotes